# How to split a character column into two columns by removing the brackets in R?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, split

I have a council data for social care expenditure at each geographic area or council which looks like this:

```
Council                     Expenditure
Cumbria (102)               100
South Tyneside (109)        200
Bexley (718)                150
Nottingham (512)            178
```

As you can see in the `Council` column of the data frame, you have the council name and their respective code given in brackets that is (102), (109) etc..

But I want to split the council names and their respective codes into two different columns and the remove the brackets around the council codes to look more like this:

```
Council          Council Code                 Expenditure
Cumbria          102                          100
South Tyneside   109                          200
Bexley           718                          150
Nottingham       178                          178
```

I have looked at other similar posts on Stackoverflow for these type of questions and used array of string operations such as `strsplit()`, `gsub()` etc. but to no avail. I am having difficulty with the brackets in particular.

Can you please suggest how can I perform this in **R**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(reshape2)
colsplit(string = gsub(pattern = "\\(|\\)",replacement = "",x = Council$Council),
     pattern = " ",names = c("Council","Council_code"))
```

**Result:**

```
    Council Council_code
1. Cumbria          102
2. South Tyneside   109
3. Bexley           718
4. Nottingham       512
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one way of getting it done using `grouping` with `regular expression`:

#### Data:

```
Council <- read.table(
  text = "Council,Expenditure
Cumbria (102),100
South Tyneside (109),200
Bexley (718),150
Nottingham (512),78",
  header = T,
  sep = ",",
  stringsAsFactors = F
)
```

#### Code:

```
Council <- transform(Council,
       # Get the Coucil_Code column
       Council_Code = as.numeric(gsub("([^\\d]+)(\\d+)(\\))","\\2",
                                               Council, 
                                               perl = T)),
       # Clean up the Council column
       Council = trimws(gsub("([a-zA-z\\s]+)([\\d\\(\\)]+)","\\1",
                                      Council, 
                                      perl = T))
)
```

#### Output:

```
 Council        Expenditure Council_Code
 Cumbria        100         102         
 South Tyneside 200         109         
 Bexley         150         718         
 Nottingham      78         512
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Abdou. This is indeed very helpful and the code works!

Answer (score 2):

A `tidyr` option is `extract`

```
library(tidyr)
extract(df1, Council, into = c("Council", "CouncilCode"), "([^(]+)\\s+\\(([0-9]+).")
#         Council CouncilCode Expenditure
#1        Cumbria         102         100
#2 South Tyneside         109         200
#3         Bexley         718         150
#4     Nottingham         512          78
```

Comment: Thank you! The code is very simple and concise. tidyr is a very useful package. I need to practice and use tidyr more often to clean data.

Answer (score 1):

Using `gsub`:

```
res <- setNames(data.frame(trimws(gsub("[[:digit:]\\()]","",df$Council))
                    , df$Expenditure, gsub("[^[:digit:]]","",df$Council)),
                c("Council","Expenditure","Council Code"))

#         Council Expenditure Council Code
#1        Cumbria         100          102
#2 South Tyneside         200          109
#3         Bexley         150          718
#4     Nottingham          78          512
```

- `[[:digit:]\\()]`: To extract only names
- `[^[:digit:]]`: To extract numbers

Comment: Thank you very much. This is indeed very helpful.